# Java Regular Expression: what is " '- "

Tags: java, regex, syntax

I came up to a line in java that uses regular expressions.
It needs a user input of Last Name

```
return lastName.matches( "[a-zA-z]+([ '-][a-zA-Z]+)*" );
```

I would like to know what is the function of the [ '-].
Also why do we need both a "+" and a "*" at the same time, and the [ '-][a-zA-Z] is in brackets?

Comment: It's just an ordinary character class, same as `[a-zA-Z]`. It matches a space, a single quote, and a dash.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of `java.util.regex.Pattern` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RE is: `[a-zA-z]+([ '-][a-zA-Z]+)*`

I'll break it down into its component parts:

- `[a-zA-Z]+`

  The string must begin with any letter, `a-z` or `A-Z`, repeated one or more times (`+`).
- `([ '-][a-zA-Z]+)*`

  - `[ '-]`

  Any single character of `<space>`, `'`, or `-`.

  - `[a-zA-Z]+`

  Again, any letter, `a-z` or `A-Z`, repeated once or more times.

  This combination of letters (`'-` and `a-ZA-Z`) may then be repeated zero or more times.

Why `[ '-]`? To allow for hiphenated names, such as `Higgs-Boson` or names with apostrophes, such as `O'Reilly`, or names with spaces such as `Van Dyke`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `[ '-]` means "one of `'`, , or `-`". The order is very important - the dash must be the last one, otherwise the character class would be considered a range, and other characters with code points between the space and the quote `'` would be accepted as well.

`+` means "one or more repetitions"; `*` means "zero or more repetitions", referring to the term of the regular expression preceding the `+` or `*` modifier.]

Overall, the expression matches groups of lowercase and uppercase letters separated by spaces, dashes, or single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

it means it can be any of the characters `space` `'` or `-`  ( space, quote dash )

the `-`  can be done as `\-`    as it also can mean a range... like `a-z`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is a pattern to match double-barreled (space or hyphen) or I-don't-know-what-to-call-it names like `O'Grady`... for example:

It would match

```
counter-terrorism
De'ville
O'Grady
smith-jones
smith and wesson
```

But it will not match

```
jones-
O'Learys'
#hashtag
Bob & Sons
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, after the first `[A-Za-z]+` consumes all the letters it can, the match will end right there unless the next character is a space, an apostrophe, or a hyphen (`[ '-]`).  If one of those characters is present, it must be followed by at least one more letter.

A lot of people have difficulty with this.  The naively write something like `[A-Za-z]+[ '-]?[A-Za-z]*`, figuring both the separator and the extra chunks of letters are optional.  But they're not *independently* optional; if there is a separator (`[ '-]`), it **must** be followed by at least one more letter.  Otherwise it would treat strings like `R'- j'-'` as valid.  Your regex doesn't have that problem.

By the way, you've got a typo in your regex: `[a-zA-z]`.  You want to watch out for that, because `[A-z]` does match all the uppercase and lowercase letters, so it will seem to be working correctly as long as the inputs are valid.  But it also matches several non-letter characters whose code points happen to lie between those of `Z` and `a`.  And very few IDEs or regex tools will catch that error.